# Unreal engine - flashlight goes dark on 180 degrees rotation

Tags: unreal-engine4, light

I have a problem with a flashlight attached to first-person character.
The problem is that whenever I rotate my character more than 180 degrees, my spotlight goes dark. When I rotate back the spotlight is OK again. But it seems to me like there is an "invisible border" moving with the character and blocking the light after the certain rotation.
To make it even worse this is only with landscape and not static meshes, which are lighted normally. So is that problem with the first-person character or some landscape lightmass or whatever?
I have attached some screenshots[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh7pZ.jpg) for you to imagine.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps the flashlight is behind the camera when your turn 180? You could try a point light to see if there is a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have found out that this wasnt a problem of the character, but the landscape material. It took me a while to figure this out, but the fix was pretty easy than. Anyway thanks for reply and marking this as closed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that this was not a problem of the character, but of the material itself. The problem is fixed now.

Comment: How did you fix the problem? Someone else might run into the same issue.

Comment: Material normals were badly configured and connected to a texture sample for some reason. After removing this connection everything was fine. Just a stupid mistake.